# Dual Booting with Ubuntu (GParted Problem)

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, partitioning

I wanted to dual boot Debian with my Ubuntu machine, but I cannot seem to create a partition using GParted. I go to "Create a Partition" but it's greyed out and I can't click "New".

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I'd just started using Linux and I've used Windows all my life.

Thank you!

EDIT: Going into a live usb didn't work.

Comment: Open terminal and write `sudo gparted`

Comment: I cannot partition still.

Comment: What's the current partition layout? Is there any unallocated space? Do you mean that "Create a Partition" is grayed out, and you can click it, but nothing happens, or is there another reason why you can't click it?

Comment: My main (dev/sda1 [/])

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to modify an existing partition (for example, to shrink one in order to make room for another), you cannot if the partition is in use.  This is indicated by a key icon in gparted showing that the partition is locked.

For example, in the image below, /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda6 are locked.

[image]

You can work around this by booting your system using a live USB and then performing the desired gparted actions.

I strongly suggest that you have solid, tested backups of any data that you consider important before performing partition operations.

Comment: Will try and then get back to you.

Comment: I'm trying to make a new partition, and my USB won't boot for some reason.